# One to many chat with XMPP

Tags: xmpp, xiff

I am developing a XMPP chat with XIFF library using Flex.
My problem is I want to develop a customer service chat system. When user enter my program they will only see one service man and service man will see all users.

When I tried with XIFF, I developed small chat program like google talk. First, users need to to add buddy. Second, users need to go Multiuser chat room (but Multiuser chat room will see all participants).

Can any one give me an idea or approach to success?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

using single chat and multiple connection.

If User==Service Man => send chat to all users one-by-one

If User!=Service Man => Send chat to Service Man